# Make changes in text, except parts in angle brackets

Tags: python, regex

Assuming having the following text,

```
dogs are very nice <a href="http://dogs.com">read about nice dogs here</a>
```

I need to change everything that is not in angle brackets, so the text will be

```
cats are very nice <a href="http://dogs.com">read about nice cats here</a>
```

I've found that regex `\([^)]*\)` can come in handy here, but it looks that it does not working:

```
s = 'dogs are very nice <a href="http://dogs.com">read about nice dogs here</a>'
s = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', 'cats', s)
print(s)
'dogs are very nice <a href="http://dogs.com">read about nice dogs here</a>'
```

I'm sorry if this question looks lame, but I'm really new to regex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `r'\([^)]*\)'` matches texts like `(....(....)`. It is not handy here. Note that regex tags may contain other tags, and thus, regex might not be the best tool here.

Comment: For the given example, use the regex [`dogs([^<>]*)(?=<|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cg3tHf/1) and replace each match with `cats\1`

Comment: Looks like I need to start reading Jeffrey Friedl...

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you want - there isn't even a mention of "dog" in there, let alone angle brackets. What it does, specifically, is match any text inside round parentheses (eg. `(abc)`).

More generally, I don't think you'll be able to use regular expressions here.

If the HTML doesn't contain any other angle brackets (quite an assumption), you might be successful with `(<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*dogs`, which should match "dogs" only if each "<" preceding it is eventually followed by a ">".

But seriously, just install something like Beautiful Soup and parse the HTML; it's easy and a lot more robust.

Comment: Thanks Christof, i’ll give a try to bs4